# Disabling right click option on the web-browser control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Sorry the last question I asked was a bit mistake.I havent mentioned the web-browser in it.My question is I am able to right click on the web-browser control in silverlight,I dont want to do it.Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the context menu with this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="silverlightObjDiv">
    <!-- silverlight object here -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('silverlightObjDiv').oncontextmenu = disableRightClick;
function disableRightClick(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hi stian sir my webrowser control in the webpage with .xaml extension

Comment: you don't controll this in your .xaml - this code is used in the page that hosts your silverlight component.

Comment: stian I did as you said.I am able to do the right click and save the picture.Is der any other option.

Comment: This code is only disabling right click on your silverlight component, if you need to disable right click on the whole page try following this example: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noright3.htm

Comment: hello stian sir my problem is I need a html viewer or Iframe without right click option in .xaml files in silverlight.But I am unable to do it with current scenario.could you help me out on this issue sir

Answer (score 0):

To disable the right click menu simply hook a right click event handler with the following code on the main grid of the page.

```
    private void btnRightClick_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

The e.handled = true make sure that right click is handled by your code. This will also remove the silverlight right click context menu.

If you need more details let me know.

cheers,

Comment: Hi carl still im getting the right click in the out of browser.Im not able to control it

Comment: To which component have you attached your handler ? Does it get executed when you do a right click in the application ?